# Websocket session replication in Hazelcast

Tags: spring-boot, session, websocket, hazelcast, spring-websocket

Is there any way to store 
    `org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession`
object in distributed data grid of hazelcast since they're not implementing interface `Serializable`?

Comment: any object to be stored in the cluster needs to have some way of serialization since it might need to travel over the network. Why do you need to store `WebSocketSession` in a distributed way though?

Comment: check spring-session project https://spring.io/projects/spring-session, it can use hazelcast as storage